# Expected ( or [

Tags: android

In this line of code,I have error,in which said that "(" or "[" is expected,
what did i do wrong?

```
DatePickerDialog datePicker=new DatePickerDialog (MainActivity.this,
new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    };
```

Comment: `new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { });`

Comment: Expected after "new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener" and before "{"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here Is the fix. You are just missing some brackets.

```
DatePickerDialog datePicker=new DatePickerDialog (MainActivity.this,
new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    });
```